# Brightness fluctuations depending on screen content

Tags: 22.04, brightness

The brightness changes depending on what screen I am on. Generally, it's a useful thing, but when I'm browsing some code on VSCode, it flickers so fast, it gets too irritating. It's happening with other applications as well but it's almost unnoticeable. I am trying to find a way to turn it off. I can't seem to find it on the settings UI. Please suggest solutions or workarounds if there is nothing I can do.

I have been facing this since Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and now even after upgrading to 22.04, I can't find any option to disable it.

Dell Lattitude 3420

Ubuntu 22.04